# VS2017 WinForms Designer Creating second Constructor on change

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, visual-studio-2017

In a fresh project, I create a form called FormMain (or any other form, it doesn't matter). This creates the FormMain.cs and a FormMain.Designer.cs. The program builds and launches just fine at this point.

But when I make any change on the GUI Designer (like changing the Form property or adding a MenuStrip from the toolbox) I see that a FormMain.resx is also created and with it, a FormMain1.Designer.cs.

It is then, I get an error

`Error  CS0111  Type 'FormMain' already defines a member called '.ctor' with the same parameter types`

I realized that **this is due to the creation of a second constructor under the partial FormMain class**, in the newly generated **FormMain1.Designer.cs** that conflicts with the one in **FormMain.cs**.

If I delete the constructor in the **FormMain1.Designer.cs**, the project builds and runs fine. But if I make further changes on the form, the constructor gets created again in **FormMain1.Designer.cs** and the error repeats. I need the constructor in **FormMain.cs** and don't want to delete that.

**So basically, I can't make changes on the form without deleting the 2nd constructor every time** I make a change on the GUI editor. Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.14)? If it is, any known fix?

Comment: I cannot see the use of adding Formmain1.designer.cs
FormMain.Designer.cs IS what you see into the GUI editor: if you need to modify that file, why  not modifying the original one?

Comment: Yes, it turns out an extension was creating the FormMain1.Designer.cs. Fixed by removing the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by removing [**Extended Strongly Typed Resource Generator**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LongLiang.ExtendedStronglyTypedResourceGenerator-18702) from Visual Studio. This stops the **FormMain1.Designer.cs** from being created everytime the form is edited.